# How do I redirect incoming requests from domain.com to www.domain.com via HTTP and HTTPS using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the script:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Rewrite rule to redirect /old to /new

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old$
RewriteRule   . /new [L,R=301]
```

Which will redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com, but would like this script to work the same if a user requests the URL via HTTPS? I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.... =/

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you’re using HTTPS and HTTPS request are handled by the same virtual host or directed to the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this can't be done in our case.... apparently because the certificate must first be accepted by the browser. In the event that it is not accepted, the redirect will not be allowed to occur because of the browser's "warning" message.

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=885150

Comment: HTTP is HTTP over SSL. So the SSL connection has to be established before the HTTP request can be sent. So, yes, the certificate has to be accepted before a HTTP redirect can happen.

Comment: "We're not using an accepted SSL certificate" would've been relevant information. It changes the question quite a bit

Comment: The purpose of the question was to mitigate the issue of not having a certificate for domain.com and only for www.domain.com - but we've now figured out that this won't work as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case, my certificate was for domain.com and not www.domain.com. What happen is if the user types https://www.domain.com it will go to the SSL error page of our server if the user insist on continuing to the page. what I did was add this tag to that error page HTML head section (error page location varies depending on the server):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://domain.com/" />
```

It will redirect the user to domain.com. It is not advisable to do this, but if you can't afford a wildcard certificate for now, its a quick workaround.